# Помогите, пожалуйста разобраться в задаче по информатике 5-6 класс

Tags: олимпиада, информатика

В школе объявили сбор пластика, макулатуры, стекла, батареек и люминесцентных ламп для вторичной переработки и экологичной утилизации. Сбор проводили в три этапа, и администрация школы решила наградить класс, который соберет на каждом из них минимум 50 у.е. сырья. Не все классы сдали все виды сырья. У администрации школы есть три таблицы с информацией по сбору пластика, макулатуры, стекла, батареек и люминесцентных ламп, но некоторые данные были повреждены. Определите минимальные неизвестные собранные нормы, которые обозначены в таблице как Z,W,Y[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я "Собранную норму" поделила на, то количество классов, которые собирали данную норму. Далее по каждому классу я сложила получившиеся "нормы" и составила уравнение для каждого класса поэтапно, с учетом, что минимальное количество должно получится 50 у.е. Далее взяла самое минимальное значение на каждом этапе. В итоге у меня получилось: W=23, Z=24, Y=27.
В правильном направлении я мылю или данное решение НЕ ВЕРНО?

Еще есть мысль, о том, что данная "норма" - это норма для каждого класса! Тогда я сложила по каждому классу все нормы сырья, которые они собрали поэтапно. Учла, что минимальное количество единиц сырья должно составлять 50. В итоге у меня получилось: W=3, Z=0, Y=0.
Но получившиеся значения меня смущают.

Comment: 50 у. е. сырья - это норма, включающая все виды сырья, которую класс  должен собрать на одном этапе.

Comment: Условие задачи неполное, решить её невозможно. "Определите минимальные неизвестные собранные нормы", чтобы получилось что?

Comment: Ну и конечно, заголовок "Собранная норма, у. е." вводит в некоторый ступор. Вероятно, имелось ввиду собранное количество.

Comment: Действительно "Собранная норма"  создает много вопросов. Данное понятие не уточнено.
Это и ставит в ступор при решении данной задачи.

Comment: Задача была включена в олимпиаду по информатике  5-6 классы.

Comment: То, что задача олимпиадная, не говорит о её качестве.

Comment: Задача, кстати, к информатике практически никакого отношения не имеет, так, система линейных уравнений.

Comment: Я даже спорить не буду, это действительно так. Соглашусь с MBo, что составители таких творений - больные

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Думаю, что Y = 7

```
 Y = Max(50 - (10+20+13), 50 - (10+17+20), 50 - (10+17+20+13))
```

P.S. Составители таких творений - больные

Comment: Спасибо. Данное решение это второй вариант моего решения. В задаче стоит вопрос - определить минимальные неизвестные. Исходя из этого Y=-10, но мы не можем написать отрицательное число. Значит ли это, что Y будет равен 0?

Comment: Для того, чтобы найти **минимальное** неизвестное, нужно взять **максимальное** из значений, обеспечивающих сумму 50. Понятно, что это не вполне тривиально, но логика такая - если мы возьмем меньше этой величины, то хотя бы для одного из классов сумма 50 не получится - поэтому эта величина - минимально допустимая.

Comment: Я вас поняла, спасибо, что помогли разобраться

Comment: Рад, что разобрались